# Crash: Attempted to dequeue multiple cells for the same index path, which is not allowed

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift5

I have tableview datasource func to build a cell from a factory method function.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        return OWTableViewOrganizer.instance.configureCell(at: indexPath)!
    }
```

The factory method is here:

```
func configureCell(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell? {
 
        var cell = UITableViewCell()
        
        switch indexPath.section {
        case thisWorkoutSections.barbel.sectionNumber():
            cell = barebellCell(indexPath: indexPath)
            break
        case thisWorkoutSections.lastWorkout.sectionNumber():           
            cell = lastWorkoutCell(indexPath: indexPath)
            break
        case thisWorkoutSections.personalRecord.sectionNumber():
            cell = personalRecordCell(indexPath: indexPath)
            break
        case thisWorkoutSections.notes.sectionNumber():
            
            break
        default:
            break
        }
        
        return cell
    }
```

I have this code to build the cell:

```
func lastWorkoutCell(indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: WorkoutSetTableViewCell.cellIdentifier(), for: indexPath) as! WorkoutSetTableViewCell
        
        if OWTableViewOrganizer.instance.lastWorkoutExerciseSets.count > 0 {
            if indexPath.row < OWTableViewOrganizer.instance.lastWorkoutExerciseSets.count {
                let logExerciseSet = OWTableViewOrganizer.instance.lastWorkoutExerciseSets[indexPath.row]
                let setNumber = indexPath.row + 1
                if let weight = logExerciseSet.weight?.doubleValue, let reps = logExerciseSet.reps?.intValue {
                    cell.setupCellWithData(setNumber: setNumber, weight: weight, reps: reps)
                }
            } else {
                cell.setupCellWithData(setNumber: -1, weight: 0, reps: 0)
            }
        } else {
            cell.setupCellWithData(setNumber: -1, weight: 0, reps: 0)
        }
        
        return cell
    }
```

But time to time this line crashes for me:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: WorkoutSetTableViewCell.cellIdentifier(), for: indexPath) as! WorkoutSetTableViewCell
```

With error:

```
Attempted to dequeue multiple cells for the same index path, which is not allowed. If you really need to dequeue more cells than the table view is requesting, use the -dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: method (without an index path)
```

I know code style and design is not ideal here, please skip this if you have comments.

I don't know where to look, I tried simply remove indexPath, but it looks does not help or bring even more issues:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: WorkoutSetTableViewCell.cellIdentifier()) as! WorkoutSetTableViewCell
```

I have one controller which presents another one at the top of it (like in Apple music) and I can swipe down to show bottom controller and swipe up to bring back top controller. I noticed in log that I have some presentation alert, not sure if this something I need to deal with to resolve the issue above but JFY info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like there are two table view trigger

```
tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
```

and you only dequeue cell from 1 table view at

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: WorkoutSetTableViewCell.cellIdentifier(), for: indexPath) as! WorkoutSetTableViewCell
```

You should try to pass `tableView` from

```
tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
```

to

```
lastWorkoutCell(indexPath: IndexPath)
```

(which will become `lastWorkoutCell(indexPath: IndexPath, tableView: UITableView)`) and dequeue cell from `tableView`